# Как создать конфигурационный файл sqlexpress?

Tags: sql

Подскажите, как создать конфигурационный файл `sqlexpress`, а затем его прикрутить к установщику?

Answer (score 1):

Для установки достаточно правильно указать параметры командной строки (по аналогии ищем для нужной вам версии):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Здесь описано как запустить на устновку в режиме записи параметров в конфигурационный файли и устновку с исопльзованием оного:

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/InstallShieldSilent.htm